# when running vba script, getting error that macro is not available or all macros may be disabled

Tags: excel, vba, automation, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have several scripts that were working fine until recently. They were running through a task scheduler and when the task scheduler opens the script it gets the following:
[image: error display message]

line 20 is this:

```
'Execute Macro Code
  ExcelApp.Run MacroPath
```

here is the full script:

```
'Input Excel File's Full Path
  ExcelFilePath = "C:\vba-files\task_sched\task_modules.xlsm"

'Input Module/Macro name within the Excel File
  MacroPath = "Module1.get_data"

'Create an instance of Excel
  Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Do you want this Excel instance to be visible?
  ExcelApp.Visible = false

'Prevent any App Launch Alerts (ie Update External Links)
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open Excel File
  Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)

'Execute Macro Code
  ExcelApp.Run MacroPath

'Save Excel File (if applicable)
  wb.Save

'Reset Display Alerts Before Closing
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True

'Close Excel File
  wb.Close

'End instance of Excel
  ExcelApp.Quit

'Leaves an onscreen message!
  MsgBox "Your Automated Task successfully ran at " & TimeValue(Now), vbInformation
```

macro settings are enabled as seen here:[image]

when the workbook is opened and the macro is ran manually it works fine.
it is just erroring out when ran through the script

Comment: Is the task scheduler running with your credentials?

Comment: yes, the task scheduler will fire fine. When I change excel visible to true it will open the workbook and then it will display the error message.

Comment: That wasn't my question. I assume you are using the Windows Task Scheduler? Every task is executed with a specific user account (often this is "System"). Unless you specify your own user for the task, the task runs with the privileges and settings of that user and that may be different.

Comment: the task scheduler is running under my profile, I am blocked from admin prev. However, if I run the vba-script as a standalone the same error will occur

Comment: I cannot imagine how could it work fine... Your VBScript code should fully qualify the procedure to be called. I mean, it also needs the workbook name (or full name) where the macro to be called exists. Please, try `ExcelApp.run "'" & ExcelFilePath & "'" & "!" & MacroPath`

Comment: Try adding `excelapp.automationsecurity = 1` before opening the workbook?

Comment: @FaneDuru that worked. Thank you. I am really confused. How come it was working before? It was working for about 2 weeks with no problems.

Comment: I cannot understand, neither... The `Run` method **needs to know which procedure of which workbook** to be called. Sometimes, Excel tries guessing... If no other workbook, xlb, add-in open, it maybe calls the single procedure matching the call string. I never tried that...

Comment: @FaneDuru it's magic. can you go ahead and post the answer?

Comment: @Rory that is interesting. I did a quick google search of ```excelapp.automationsecurity = 1``` however I am not sure I understand what it does?

Comment: OK. I will transform the comment in an answer...

Comment: It makes macro security low for any workbooks opened by your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot understand how could it work fine before... Basically, your VBScript code should fully qualify the procedure to be called. I mean, it also needs the workbook name (or full name) where the macro to be called exists. Please, try:

```
 ExcelApp.run "'" & ExcelFilePath & "'" & "!" & MacroPath
```

`"'"` characters make the code running well even if the file path contains spaces...

In theory, using the workbook full name will automatically open the workbook keeping the macro, **if not open**... I did not test it on automation from VBScript. It works in this way when make the call from Excel (tested)

Comment: I googled about `ExcelApp.run` on Microsoft site ,but no mention for 
**' characters** (no offense) ,but we need to learn.

Comment: Then, try placing the workbook in a path containing spaces and run its macto. It is only a precaution.

Comment: I am fully trust all of your answers, ok no problem.

Comment: @Waleed It shouldn't be a matter of trust... If you have any doubts you mut not avoiding to ask about it. I used the above way in hundreds of cases, since Excel 2003. I think is a general rule in Excel. It is important in formulas, too. Microsoft maybe updated the last versions to work without it, but I did not even test in such a way. Since it worked well in that way and is still accepted, I do not see any reason to renounce at it...